# Using two different Schemas in NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I have a nodeJs application which is working fine with one schema from MSSQL, but i have a requirement where i need to use another schema and do some api calls.

first API is working fine and giving out result.
 But when I tried with another get api named "/stockOrderDetails" it is just giving empty data like this:

Can anyone please let me know how to use different schemas in a single JS file for nodeJS

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "status": "OK",
  "message": "Data Operation Success",
  "data": {
    "orderDetail": [

    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my actual code:

````
const express = require("express");
var sql = require("mssql");

const { json, urlencoded } = require("body-parser");

const multer = require("multer");

var config = {
  user: "jsudjac",
  password: "********",
  server: "********",
  database: "JSULLC_Test",
};
var dataSource = {
  user: "jsudjac",
  password: "*****",
  server: "*********",
  database: "Stock_Test",
};

const dbconn1 = sql.connect(config, (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Connected to the database");
  } else {
    console.log("Problem in connecting to database");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("testing");
  }
});

const dbconn2 = sql.connect(dataSource, (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("connected");
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const app = express();
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  dest: "./uploads/",
}).single("file");
app.use(json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/jsuOrderDetails/:jsuOrder", (req, res) => {
  const request = new sql.Request(dbconn1);
  request.input("jsuOrder", sql.VarChar, req.params.jsuOrder);
  request.execute("mobile_getOrderDetails", (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      var out = {
        code: 200,
        status: "OK",
        message: "Data Operation Success",
        data: {
          orderDetail: result.recordsets[0],
        },
      };
    } else {
      var out = {
        status: 404,
        data: {},
      };
    }
    res.send(out);
  });
});

app.get("/stockOrderDetails/:jsuOrder", (req, res) => {
  const request = new sql.Request(dbconn2);
  console.log("hithithit");
  request.input("jsuOrder", sql.VarChar, req.params.jsuOrder);
  console.log(req.params.jsuOrder);
  request.execute("mobile_getOrderDetails", (err, result) => {
    if (!err) {
      var out = {
        code: 200,
        status: "OK",
        message: "Data Operation Success",
        data: {
          orderDetail: result.recordsets[0],
        },
      };
    } else {
      var out = {
        status: 404,
        data: {},
      };
    }
    res.send(out);
  });
});

app.get("/validate", (req, res) => {
  let query = "select * from ma_smallpipe_coating_details";
  console.log("hithit");
  dbconn2.query(query, (err, rows) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(rows.recordsets[0]);
    }
  });
});```
````

Comment: Something like `request.execute("OtherSchema.mobile_getOrderDetails", (err, result) . . .`?

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you very much.